# How can I update Python code based on API endpoint?

Tags: python

I'm working in a voice assistant, made with Python, and I want to be able to update my code when a newer version of the script is avaliable (I'll use a API endpoint to do that). This endpoint would be something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.10",
    "date": "01/06/2020",
    "commands:" [
        {"keyword": "hey", "action": "say('hello')"},
        ...
    ]
}
```

Note that I have Python code in the endpoint, and I want to replace the local copy by that code in the API.

The api check logic I have so far looks like this:

```
if new_version > actual_version:
    update() -> *download the code and update the local copy*
else:
    pass
```

The proble is: what I'm trying to update it's the **code itself**.

Is that possible?

I'm also thinking in updating a Python module, and the restarting the app to catch the updates.

Comment: @Jan What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is probably better asked on another Stack Exchange network, I'll have a stab at an alternate solution.

A common way to solve this problem is to run a series of services, distributing responsibilities between them, such as redirecting traffic to or updating/restarting later ones.

Limiting the scope of each program to one purpose (network requests, updating voice assist, voice assist..) will likely also help each be more stable, reliable, and testable.

---

In your case, you might consider having the initial API be quite simple and normally just pass the request to the real service. This would allow you to add an endpoint capable of executing an update tool, along with setting the foward/simple API to send a different web response, etc. while the main service is starting.

```
                                           +----------+
                                           |          |
                                           |  Voice   |
                                     +---->|  Service |<----+
   +----------+       +---------+    |     |          |     |
   | queueing |       |         |    |     +----------+     | (end running?)
   | frontend |+----->|  Simple |+---+                      | update
   | (Nginx?) |       |  API    |          +----------+     | restart
   +----------+       |         |+---+     |          |     |
                      +---------+    |     |  Update  |     |
                                     +---->|  Logic   |+----+
                                           |          |
                                           +----------+
```

Created with [ascii-flow](http://stable.ascii-flow.appspot.com/#Draw)

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can you explain that better? Thank you!

Comment: @AfonsoSantos I've added a diagram to help explain the system

Comment: Thank you for the help! That diagram pretty much sums up what I will do!